# Group by Id and create an array from the grouped data

Tags: javascript, angular, group-by, lodash

In my angular application, i am getting the response as follows.

```js
[{
    "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37330fb5",
    "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
    "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
    "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
    "status": "Approved"
}, {
    "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b373306b5",
    "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
    "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
    "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
    "status": "Approved"
}]
```

i have two classes on the application as,

**ProposalGroup.ts**

```
export class ProposalGroup {
    eventId: string;
    proposalGpId: string;
    proposals: Proposal[];
}
```

**Proposal.ts**

```
export class Proposal {
    proposalId: string;
    listingId: Date;
    eventId: Price;
    status: string;
}
```

I need to create an array of ProposalGroups out of the above JSON, when to proposals have the same listingId It should be grouped.

I want to generate an **`output`** as follows,

```js
[{
    "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
    "proposals": [{
        "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37330fb5",
        "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
        "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
        "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
        "status": "approved"
    }, {
        "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b373306b5",
        "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
        "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
        "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
        "status": "approved"
    }]
}]
```

this is what i have tried using lodash,

```
const grouped = _.groupBy(this.proposals, (proposal: Proposal) => proposal.listingId);
```

but the above gives a dictionary.

Comment: Can an event have proposals from multiple listings? Because in that case you can't have everything in one array. Or are you talking about nested arrays, i.e. an array of grouped proposal arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group and then map the groups to a new array:

```js
const proposals = [{"proposalId":"cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37330fb5","proposalGpId":"cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5","eventId":"17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e","listingId":"pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1","status":"Approved"},{"proposalId":"cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b373306b5","proposalGpId":"cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5","eventId":"17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e","listingId":"pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1","status":"Approved"}];

const result = _(proposals)
  .groupBy('listingId') // group by listingId
  .map((proposals, listingId) => (({
    eventId: proposals[0].eventId, // omit this if you don't want the eventId
    listingId, // omit it if you don't want the listingId
    proposals
  })))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var proposals = [{
    "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37330fb5",
    "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
    "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
    "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
    "status": "Approved"
}, {
    "proposalId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b373306b5",
    "proposalGpId": "cc0bcd90-fc75-4c73-bd66-799b37380fb5",
    "eventId": "17e69ea1-54da-11e7-9469-985aebe2005e",
    "listingId": "pdf19f7e1-5f2b-4d02-a48d-3b6d0189b5d1",
    "status": "Approved"
}];

console.log('proposals : ', _.chain(/*this.*/proposals)

    .groupBy("listingId")
    .transform((result, value, key)=>{
        result.push({"listingId": key, proposals: value});
    }, [])
    .value()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This will convert dictionary into array of objects.

Comment: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'LoDashExplicitObjectWrapper<Dictionary<Proposal[]>>'.'

Comment: Try out the snippet updated by @Peter Selinger, my answer was based on latest lodash documentation.